# React Native: Wait until action is completed and reducers sets the state

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-ios

I am new to react native and using redux for state management. 
My component is not waiting till the reducer sets the state and returns the initial state.
which leads to empty object without data.

**This is my Component**

```
function SingleProject({ route, getSingleProject, data: { singleProject } }) {
  useEffect(() => {
     getSingleProject(route.params.itemId);
  }, [getSingleProject, route.params.itemId]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Text>{singleProject && singleProject.data.name}</Text>
 </Container>
  );
}

SingleProject.propTypes = {
  getSingleProject: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProp = (state) => ({
  data: state.project,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProp, { getSingleProject })(SingleProject);
```

**This is my action**

```
export const getSingleProject = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: await AsyncStorage.getItem("token"),
    },
  };
  await axios
    .get(`${API_URL}/project/single/${id}`, config)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_SINGLE_PROJECT,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_SINGLE_PROJECT_ERROR,
        payload: err,
      });
    });
};
```

**This is my reducer**

```
const initiaState = {
  data: null,
  singleProject: {},
  loading: true,
  error: "",
};

export default function (state = initiaState, actions) {
  const { type, payload } = actions;

  switch (type) {
 case GET_SINGLE_PROJECT:
      return {
        ...state,
        singleProject: payload,
        loading: false,
      };

 default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

So basically i want my component to wait until the state is updated. I have used mapStateToprop function but i don't know why it is not working.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using async/await and Promise(.then) both. That might be the issue. try removing async/await.

```
export const getSingleProject = (id) => (dispatch) => {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: await AsyncStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      };
      axios
        .get(`${API_URL}/project/single/${id}`, config)
        .then((res) => {
          dispatch({
            type: GET_SINGLE_PROJECT,
            payload: res.data,
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          dispatch({
            type: GET_SINGLE_PROJECT_ERROR,
            payload: err,
          });
        });
    };
```

Comment: I tried promise alone and async await alone. It still doesn't work. I kept a condition in the jsx of component as a temporary patch but i don't think that is correct way but it's working.